# Java program Number format exception in long array?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, long-integer, numberformatexception

I am writing a code for taking some very large  numbers (10^8 order) and my program is throwing the number format exception. This is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class sticker
{
    public static void main(String gs[])
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        long a[]=new long[40];
        int n=0,i,k=0;
        String x;

        try {
            x=in.readLine();
            n=Integer.parseInt(x); // n is the number of inputs
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                x=in.readLine();
                a[i]=Long.parseLong(x);
            }

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(a[i]<=300000000)
                    k++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException: "+nfe.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i have done the mistake??

Error:

```
2
18 200000000
NumberFormatException: For input string: "18 200000000"


0
```

Comment: "18 200000000" is obviously not a valid number because of the space

Comment: I have entered 2 as the number of inputs, so i have to give 2 numbers and I gave 18 and 200000000 as my inputs.

Comment: space is not a delimiter to end the number I think so !! Ideally it is enter !!??!?!

Comment: But you are parsing the whole line with `a[i]=Long.parseLong(x);`. You need to separate the two numbers that you are trying to input before calling `parseLong()`.

Comment: My basic program is to use the faster method to enter inputs and since buffer reader is faster than scanner, I used it. Is there any way i could use buffer reader and the inputs are separated by space and not by "enter" key?

Comment: do you really think 18 20000000 is a valid number?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the difference in run-time efficiency between `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`. Using `Scanner` is much easier for the coder (i.e. you) than trying to parse the String yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"18 200000000" is obviously not a valid number because of the space. Your program requires one number per line. If you want to allow multiple numbers per line, you will need to find other solutions to parse them. I can think of at least two solutions:

1. Use `split()` to split the `String` on a space.
2. Use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] lineParts = null;
String n = "18 200000000";
lineParts = n.split( " " );

long first = Long.parseLong(lineParts[0]);
long second = Long.parseLong(lineParts[1]);
```